# Mysql select date from calculated interval

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, where-clause

There is a table `concerts` which contains fields `start_date` with the format: `2019-06-08 10:00:00` and field `duration` - duration in minutes. I need to find concerts which intersect with special datetime. I'm using:

```
SELECT 
     id, duration, start_date, 
     DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL + duration MINUTE) as end_date 
FROM 
     concerts 
WHERE 
     start_date <= '2019-06-08 10:00:00' 
     and end_date >= '2019-06-08 10:00:00'
```

I can calcucate `end_date` but then I can't use it inside `where` block, only inside `having`.
How can I use `OR` expression with `where` and `having`? I've found out I can use all conditions inside `having` block, but it's bad for performance. Any suggestions?

**P.S** One more if I can use `where` **OR** `having` inside one query, or how can I replace it

Comment: Nothing prevents from `WHERE start_date <= '2019-06-08 10:00:00' HAVING end_date >= '2019-06-08 10:00:00' `

Comment: Yes, but what about I need to use `where` OR `having`?

Comment: You tell "I need to find concerts which intersect with special datetime". Intersection needs AND: `WHERE start1 < end2 AND start2 < end1`. In your case `start2=end2=timepoint`.

Comment: Ok, maybe my explanation was no so clear, in this case, you are right, but I wanna to understand if I can use `where` or `having`

Answer (score 2):

You can't access a column declared in the `select` clause in the `where` clause. Instead, you can repeat the expression.

But actually, I think that this does what you want, ie check which concerts were on-going at a specific point in time:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    duration, 
    start_date, 
    start_date + interval duration minute as end_date 
FROM concerts 
WHERE '2019-06-08 10:00:00' between start_date and start_date + interval duration minute
```